# Assign postmeta in bulk

Tags: post-meta

I have meta paramteres for my pages, which i would like to change in bulk (about 300 pages). I know that meta name is "header-settings" and values can be "no-data", "site-data" and "page-data"

I also have a functions.php script from theme developer dedicated to solve this task, but it doesn't work. So, it there any right way to mass assign this meta? I would like **header-settings** to be **page-data**

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
        'post-type' => 'page',
    )
);

foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    $value = array( 
        'header-settings' => 'page-data',
    );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_skoty-page-header-settings', $value);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I always do it...

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'header_setting_generate', 99 );

function header_setting_generate($post_id) {
    global $post;
    if(isset($_POST['post_type']) && ($_POST['post_type'] == "page")){
        $value = array( 
            'header-settings' => 'page-data',
        );

        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_skoty-page-header-settings', $value);
    }
}
```

After inserting this code, go to "Pages", Select All, click Bulk Edit, Change status to "Published" just to trigger a save_post on all pages. This should generate it.

Comment: Thank's for such quick reply! The solution is great, but doesn't work in bulk as you said. I've tried different approaches using different meta values, but it only works if I save page inside page edit. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm that's strange, I have tried this same code in numerous sites, and all of them did bulk update. Maybe you can try removing global $post or change $post_id to $post->ID and try again.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work :( And if I put $post->ID, site breaks at all